# Is טיית a language?

Tags: commentaries, translation, language, maseches-keilim

Rav Hai Ga'on's commentary to [Keilim 14:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kelim.14.3?ven=Mishnah_Yomit_by_Dr._Joshua_Kulp&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi) reads:

**הקנטר של בנאי.** פי' כמין מטה ושבט של ברזל שהוא לבנאים לחתור בו הכותל ושמו בטיית בורסין

What do the last three words mean? I assume it's a reference to another language, but which one?

Comment: שו"ת מהר"ם אלשקר סימן עד
ופי' טיית הוא לשון מהלשונות ותמצא זה פעמים רבות בערוך ועל הרוב הוא לשון ערב.

Comment: I found a reference to this language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judeo-Tat which connects it to Turkish

Comment: [Here](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=cpUm-uGaBhMC&hl=en) it is said to be a Barcelona specific reference to Arabic.

Comment: Based on the previous comments it sounds like it might be the Arabic dialect of the Tayy Arab tribe (known in Aramaic as טייעא, a term which eventually came to refer to Arabs in general). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tayy